# Complex Joins (Pyspark) - Range and Categorical

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

table 1:

| pol_no | version | cover | rf_1 | rf_2 | rf_3 | rl_1 | rl_2 | rl_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc123 | 1 | a | ["base","usage"] | ["group"] | null | ["500","private"] | ["blue"] | null |
| cde111 | 1 | a | ["base","usage"] | ["age"] | ["protection","gold_mem"," more_than_one_claim"] | ["500","private"] | ["9"] | ["Y","Y","N"] |
| cde222 | 1 | a | ["base","usage"] | ["group"] | null | ["300","business"] | ["gold"] | null |

table 2:

| rating_factor_1 | rating_factor_2 | rating_factor_3 | rating_factor_cat_a | rating_factor_cat_b | rating_factor_cat_c | rating_factor_start | rating_factor_end | rating_factor_amt | rating_factor_coeff | rating_factor_rate | version | cover |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| base | usage | null | private | null | null | 400 | 550 | 50 | 0.2 | null | 1 | a |
| base | usage | null | business | null | null | 200 | 300 | 70 | 0.4 | null | 1 | a |
| group | null | null | blue | null | null | null | null | 20 | null | 0.5 | 1 | a |
| group | null | null | gold | null | null | null | null | 30 | null | 0.8 | 1 | a |
| protection | gold_mem | more_than_one_claim | Y | Y | N | null | null | 10 | 0.4 | null | 1 | a |
| age | null | null | null | null | null | 0 | 5 | 15 | 0.5 | null | 1 | a |
| age | null | null | null | null | null | 6 | 10 | 20 | 0.8 | null | 1 | a |

I have to join Table 1 to Table 2. The catch is, there are both range and categorical joins. I will join them by version and cover. Then, for instance rf_1 in table 1 would match with rating _ factor 1 and rating _ factor 2 in table 2 and looking at values from rl_1, i would have have to join using range with table 2 and join the second factor "private" with rating _ factor _ cat _a. And append the amount, coeff and rate values back to table 1.

Output table:

| pol_no | version | cover | rf_1 | rf_2 | rf_3 | rl_1 | rl_2 | rl_3 | amt_1 | coeff_1 | rate_1 | amt_2 | coeff_2 | rate_2 | amt_3 | coeff_3 | rate_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc123 | 1 | a | ["base","usage"] | ["group"] | null | ["500","private"] | ["blue"] | null | 50 | 0.2 | null | 20 | null | 0.5 | null | null | null |
| cde111 | 1 | a | ["base","usage"] | ["age"] | ["protection","gold_mem"," more_than_one_claim"] | ["500","private"] | ["9"] | ["Y","Y","N"] | 50 | 0.2 | null | 20 | 0.8 | null | 10 | 0.4 | null |
| cde222 | 1 | a | ["base","usage"] | ["group"] | null | ["300","business"] | ["gold"] | null | 70 | 0.4 | null | 30 | null | 0.8 | null | null | null |

I think we would have to do permutations of various joins such as [category, range] , [range,category], [category,category] and [range,range] and see which joins gives at least one of the values amount,coeff,rate in the final table.

I cannot use hardcoding to get the amount,coeff and rate values, have to use loops as in actual case there are 10000 of rows of data like this.

Code modified from sparksql to pyspark:

```
# Constructing the list of expressions for the select statement
query_expressions = []

for i in range(1, 4):
    rf = f'rf_{i}'
    rl = f'rl_{i}'
    print(rl)
    jtmp_col = f'jtmp_{i}'

    expr = (
        F.when(
            (F.col(rf).isNotNull()) &
            (F.size(F.col('tab2_cat_values')) == 0) &
            (
                (rl[0] >= F.col('rating_factor_start')) &
                #print(rl[0])
                (rl[0] <= F.col('rating_factor_end'))
            ),
            F.struct(
                'rating_factor_amount',
                'rating_factor_coefficeint',
                'rating_factor_rate'
            )
        )
        # Add other when conditions similarly
        .alias(jtmp_col)
    )

    query_expressions.extend([
        expr,
        F.col(f'{jtmp_col}.rating_factor_amount').alias(f'amt_{i}'),
        F.col(f'{jtmp_col}.rating_factor_coefficeint').alias(f'coeff_{i}'),
        F.col(f'{jtmp_col}.rating_factor_rate').alias(f'rate_{i}')
    ])

# Creating the DataFrame
df = (
    df1.join(df2, (['version','cover']))
    .select(
        "pol_no", "version", "cover", "rf_1", "rl_1", "rf_2", "rf_3", "rl_2", "rl_3","rating_factor_1","rating_factor_2","rating_factor_3",
        F.array(F.col("rating_factor_cat_a"), F.col("rating_factor_cat_b"), F.col("rating_factor_cat_c")).alias("tab2_cat_values"),
        *query_expressions
    )
     .filter(
         (
             (F.array_compact(F.array(F.col("rating_factor_1"), F.col("rating_factor_2"), F.col("rating_factor_3")))
              == F.col("rf_1")) |
             (F.array_compact(F.array(F.col("rating_factor_1"), F.col("rating_factor_2"), F.col("rating_factor_3")))
              == F.col("rf_2")) |
             (F.array_compact(F.array(F.col("rating_factor_1"), F.col("rating_factor_2"), F.col("rating_factor_3")))
              == F.col("rf_3"))
         )
     )
)

# Show or perform any further actions as needed
df.display()
```

Comment: Provide tables in markdown format rather than giving it as image, it will be helpful for reproducing. Use this link for formatting, copy and paste the table data here .https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Comment: @JayashankarGS i have provided in markdown format

Comment: Does rf1,rf2,rf3 and rl1,rl2,rl3 are constant columns else there more rf4,rf5,rf6 are there?

Comment: how big is table2 ? I would probably use a broadcast if it is small enough.

Comment: @JayashankarGS there could be rf4,rf5,rf6 in the future, but for now there is only 1-3. They are not fixed

Comment: @Steven there are 10,000 + rows for table 2

Comment: @555codewiz That's quite small. you can probably try it and see how it performs.

Comment: @Steven i am not too sure how to go about using broadcast in this case as there are multiple joins i would have to do, permutations

Comment: @JayashankarGS is there any ideas to solve this?

Comment: I have an idea that is you need to use filter conditions along with join. Only range join are can not be performed since you have intermediate category check.

Comment: I will update with code.

Comment: @JayashankarGS that would help heaps, i can only do manual joins now but that is not ideal for large tables ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking about join based on range including category simultaneously for all `rf` factor is not possible with join operations,
but combination of filter and join can achieve your output.

Here are the queries for it.

First create a temporary view of these 2 tables.

```
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("df1")
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("df2")
```

Then creating query on conditions which satisfies all `rf` factors.

```
querycon=''
for i in range(1,4):
    rf = f'rf_{i}'
    rl= f'rl_{i}'
    q = f''',case
when ((d1.{rf} is not null) and (tab2_cat_values==array()) and ((cast(d1.{rl}[0] as int) >= d2.rating_factor_start) and (cast(d1.{rl}[0] as int) <= d2.rating_factor_end))) then struct(d2.rating_factor_amt,d2.rating_factor_coeff,d2.rating_factor_rate)
when ((d1.{rf} is not null) and (tab2_cat_values!=array()) and (array_size(d1.{rl})==array_size(tab2_cat_values) and (d1.{rl}==tab2_cat_values))) then struct(d2.rating_factor_amt,d2.rating_factor_coeff,d2.rating_factor_rate)
when ((d1.{rf} is not null) and (tab2_cat_values!=array()) and (array_size(d1.{rl})>1) and (array_contains(d1.{rl},tab2_cat_values[0])) and ((cast(d1.{rl}[0] as int) >= d2.rating_factor_start) and (cast(d1.{rl}[0] as int) <= d2.rating_factor_end))) then 
struct(d2.rating_factor_amt,d2.rating_factor_coeff,d2.rating_factor_rate)
else null end as jtmp_{i},
jtmp_{i}.rating_factor_amt as amt_{i},
jtmp_{i}.rating_factor_coeff as coeff_{i},
jtmp_{i}.rating_factor_rate as rate_{i}
'''
    querycon=querycon+q
```

Here, I am looping through all factors in your case it's 3 if more factors comes in future you need to modify above cases accordingly.

In this case statement

1. It checks for category, if it is empty then it goes for checking range and takes output.
2. Then it checks if category are same in both table
3. Last if the there are more category then goes to check both category and range conditions.

This query is combined with the main joined data like below.

```
fquery=f'''select
d1.pol_no,d1.version,d1.cover,d1.rf_1,d1.rl_1,d1.rf_2,d1.rf_3,d1.rl_2,d1.rl_3,
(array_compact(array(d2.rating_factor_cat_a,d2.rating_factor_cat_b,d2.rating_factor_cat_c))) as tab2_cat_values
{querycon}
from df1 d1 
join df2 d2 on d1.version=d2.version 
and d1.cover=d2.cover 
and  (
    (array_compact(array(d2.rating_factor_1,d2.rating_factor_2,d2.rating_factor_3))==d1.rf_1)
    or (array_compact(array(d2.rating_factor_1,d2.rating_factor_2,d2.rating_factor_3))==d1.rf_2)
    or (array_compact(array(d2.rating_factor_1,d2.rating_factor_2,d2.rating_factor_3))==d1.rf_3))
'''

df = spark.sql(fquery)
```

Next select the required columns.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_set,explode_outer,col

result_cols=["amt_1","coeff_1","rate_1","amt_2","coeff_2","rate_2","amt_3","coeff_3","rate_3"]
aggexpr = [collect_set(i).alias(i) for i in result_cols]
df = df.groupBy(*df.columns[:9]).agg(*aggexpr)

for i in result_cols:
    df = df.withColumn(i,explode_outer(col(i)))
display(df)
```

Here, `*df.columns[:9]` is the columns from table 1 till `rl_3`. If you have more factors in future you need to extend the list till it.

Output:

| pol_no | version | cover | rf_1 | rl_1 | rf_2 | rf_3 | rl_2 | rl_3 | amt_1 | coeff_1 | rate_1 | amt_2 | coeff_2 | rate_2 | amt_3 | coeff_3 | rate_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc123 | 1 | a | ["base","usage"] | ["500","private"] | ["group"] | null | ["blue"] | null | 50 | 0.2 | null | 20 | 0.5 | null | null | null | null |
| cde111 | 1 | a | ["base","usage"] | ["500","private"] | ["age"] | ["protection","gold_mem","more_than_one_claim"] | ["9"] | ["Y","Y","N"] | 50 | 0.2 | null | 20 | 0.8 | null | 10 | 0.4 | null |
| cde222 | 1 | a | ["base","usage"] | ["300","business"] | ["group"] | null | ["gold"] | null | 70 | 0.4 | null | 30 | 0.8 | null | null | null | null |

[image]

Comment: i rewrote ur code using pyspark instead of spark sql, before the last step, however i am getting null values but i feel all is okay with my code

Comment: let me add the code

Comment: (rl[0] >= F.col('rating_factor_start')) &
                #print(rl[0])
                (rl[0] <= F.col('rating_factor_end')) could this be the problem??

Comment: until you don't have the another `rf` factor which length is more than 1 and having
`rl` all values as category. because here first is for range conditions second for category checking if you having another `rl` let's say `["catA","catB"]` both category then you need to add the condition for this also.

Comment: how would you add a condition for that? sorry im confused but i understand your code so far

Comment: In `querycon` need to add extra `when new_condition` which checks. As of know i have given generic condition. In future if you have different type of `rf` need check and alter accordingly.

Comment: Is there anything different `rf` factors then you are having currently?

Comment: i have provided all the possible types of RF in the example tables above so i dont think so

Comment: Ok then this conditions is enough for getting results.